# Angular - Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(allowedCommonJsDependencies)

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

While running `ng serve` I'm getting the error `Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(allowedCommonJsDependencies).` Below is the `allowedCommonJsDependencies` in `angular.json`. Can anyone help me with this?

[image]